Python Flask Docker: compose consumer launch using gunicorn and multiprocessing
I'm trying to make Docker compose using 2 projects on different ports and Apache/Kafka.
With the first project and producer all is okay, simply works fine. Kafka works fine too, but with the last I have a problem, when trying to run the project using gunicorn with consumer and app_context().
I want to keep my app_context in consumer py to create a record to db without asking Flask every time. In that case in app.py I'm using Multiprocessign to create another process with consumer, when Flask is running.
manager.py
app = create_app()


def start_consumer():
    consumer = ConsumerThread('user-tokens', app)
    consumer.start()


consumer_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=start_consumer)
consumer_process.start()


init.py
from app.api import bp as api_bp
    app.register_blueprint(api_bp, url_prefix='/api')

routes.py
@bp.route('/transport/<transport_type>/add', methods=['POST'])
in Postman, when I'm trying to make a POST request to address
localhost:8001/api/transport/truck/add
I have an error:
Could not get response
Error: socket hang up

boot.sh
#!/bin/bash
flask db upgrade
exec gunicorn -b :5000 --access-logfile - --error-logfile - manager:app

compose.yaml
  dispatcher-vehicles:
    image: dispatch_vehicles
    environment:
      SECRET_KEY: 12345abcde
    ports:
      - "8001:5000"
    build:
      context: dispatcher_vehicles
    networks:
      - compose-net

Locally, without Docker, everything works fine.
Change ports, try to test that local without Docker.
